# Reorganize scraped python indexed data into html table

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

The following script which retrieves images and text from a webpage. So far the script's output is similar to the original page with some image size and CSS modifications. Instead of having each item in a different row and a single column I would like each row in the table to be filled with as many items / columns as possible until the end of the row and fill the next row with and so one so that the output html page presents a full page and table with multiple columns and rows rather than just a single column and multiple rows. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

urldes = "https://www.johnpyeauctions.co.uk/lot_list.asp?saleid=4764&siteid=1"

# add header
mozila_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64)\
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'
headers = {'User-Agent': mozila_agent}
r = requests.get(urldes, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")


############################################################

the_whole_table = soup.find('table', width='97%')

datalist = []

for tr in the_whole_table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    # you want to start from the 1st item not the 0th so [1:]
    # Because the first is the thead i.e. Lot no, Picture, Lot Title...
    index_num = tr.find('td', width='8%')
    picture_link = index_num.next_sibling.a['data-img']
    text_info = tr.find('td', width='41%')
    current_bid = tr.find('td', width='13%')
    time_left = tr.find('td', width='19%')
    datalist.append([index_num.text, picture_link,
                     text_info.text, current_bid.text, time_left.text])

    # for pic do ... print(picture_link) as for partial text only first 20
    # characters


index = datalist[0][0]
picture = datalist[0][1]
info = datalist[0][2]
bid = datalist[0][3]
time = datalist[0][4]


df = ['Index Number', 'Picture', 'Informational text',
      'Current BID', 'Time Left now']

theads = BeautifulSoup('<table style="width:50%; color: blue; font-family: verdana; font-size: 60%;"></table>', 'lxml')
thekeys = BeautifulSoup('<thead style="color: blue; font-family: verdana; font-size: 60%;"></thead>', 'html.parser')


for i in df:
    tag = theads.new_tag('th')
    tag.append(i)
    thekeys.thead.append(tag)

theads.table.append(thekeys)
###############################################################
# The code above will initiate a table
# after that the for loop will create and populate the first row (thead)

for i in datalist:
#    thedata = BeautifulSoup('<tr style="color: blue; font-family: verdana; font-size: 50%;"></tr>', 'html.parser')
    thedata = BeautifulSoup('<tr></tr>', 'html.parser')
    # we loop through the data we collected
    # initiate a <td> </td> tag everytime we finish with one collection
    for j in i:
        if j.startswith('https'):
            img_tag = theads.new_tag('img', src=j, height='300', width='300')
            td_tag = theads.new_tag('td')
            td_tag.append(img_tag)
            thedata.tr.append(td_tag)

        else:
  #            tag = theads.new_tag('td', style="color: blue; font-family: verdana; font-size: 50%;")
            tag = theads.new_tag('td')
            tag.append(j)
            thedata.tr.append(tag)

    theads.table.append(thedata)

css = "<style>{color: blue; font-family: verdana; font-size: 50%;}</style>"
#css.string = css

with open('asdf.html', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(theads.prettify())

print(css)

# each of these if you print them you'll get a information that you can store
# to test do print(index_num.text, text_info.text)
```

A quick mockup of the output would look like this (not same image repeated obviously):
[image]

Comment: Have you considered using [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#basics) to render your HTML from a template? This tends to be easier (especially easier to read and maintain later on) than putting it together in code.

Comment: I am not familiar with it but will look into it. Thank you for the suggestion.